# convergence of $\sum_{n≥ 1}\left(\frac{n!}{a(a+1)(a+2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(a+n)(n^\alpha)}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine the convergence of the series for the $\alpha\in\mathbb{R},a>0$, to try to solve it, apply the quotient criterion as follows

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{a(a+1)(a+2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(a+n+1)((n+1)^\alpha)}\right)}{\left(\frac{n!}{a(a+1)(a+2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(a+n)(n^\alpha)}\right)}$$

If I am not mistaken, the above expression is equivalent to $\frac{n+1}{(a+n+1)(n+1)^\alpha}$ if it does not fail, I should determine the limit of this expression but I am not sure how to do it, any suggestions?

Comment: Note the expression is actually equivalent to $\frac{(n+1)n^{\alpha}}{(a+n+1)(n+1)^\alpha}$, i.e., you're missing the $n^{\alpha}$ factor in the numerator.

Comment: You could use Stirling to find that asymptotically $$\frac{n!}{a(a+1)\cdots(a+n)} \sim \frac{\Gamma(a)}{n^a} \, .$$
Hence, for convergence, you need $a+\alpha>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio test will not help. Note however that
$$
\frac{{a_{n + 1} }}{{a_n }} = \frac{{n + 1}}{{n + 1 + a}}\left( {\frac{n}{{n + 1}}} \right)^\alpha   = \frac{{1 + 1/n}}{{1 + (1 + a)/n}}\frac{1}{{(1 + 1/n)^\alpha  }} = 1 - \frac{{a + \alpha }}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right),
$$
by using the generalised binomial theorem. By the [Gauss test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html), the series converges iff $a+\alpha>1$.

Answer (score 1):

After rearranging, the desired limit to evaluate is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{n+1+a}\cdot \Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^a$$

Each factor limits to $1$; can you see why?